# How do I install "Ruby Linguistics With Verb Conjugation"?

Tags: ruby, linguistics

I downloaded the source code for "[Ruby Linguistics With Verb Conjugation](https://github.com/bdigital/ruby_linguistics_with_verb_conjugation)".

How can I install it for usage? Do I need to compile it into some gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cd into the directory and run `rake`, then install the gem:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bdigital/ruby_linguistics_with_verb_conjugation.git
$ cd ruby_linguistics_with_verb_conjugation
$ rake
...lots of output...
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: linguistics
  Version: 1.0.8
  File: linguistics-1.0.8.gem
  mv linguistics-1.0.8.gem pkg/linguistics-1.0.8.gem
$ cd pkg
$ gem install linguistics-1.0.8.gem
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Linguistics gem. Did you try `gem install linguistics`? If you're not running RVM you'll want to use `sudo`.

Comment: I installed it. But I want to know how to use this package locally. Thanks~

Comment: That is a different question. You'll need to read the docs for that.

Comment: @monadic, you are welcome to add a comment, but do not add content to an answer. I rolled it back to the previous content.

Answer (score 0):

After failing to run rake on the mac, this worked on the mac:

```
sudo gem install linguistics
```

Then, you need to run it from your script:

```
require "rubygems"
require "linguistics"
```

Thanks, Tin Man.